# sctp traffic generator

Tags: networking, traffic

I'm looking for a free SCTP/TCAP traffic generator (specially for MAP, Camel and INAP protocols).
I need to build some message flow scenario and generate load in order to test some application

Thanks

Comment: [netperf seems to support that](http://www.netperf.org/pipermail/netperf-talk/2007-June/000240.html) That's just something I found while googling the answer, though.

Comment: I've looked in the manual of netperf but couldn't find some tcap & higher levels. also this one doesn't allow me to generate some scenario.

Comment: Adding the profiling and performance tags to your question was intended to help improve the odds of you getting an answer to your question. The tools you're looking for are going to be those used in profiling and performance tuning so the people you're looking for are probably going to be sitting on those tags.

Comment: Also, you may want to update your question with the exact scenario and application you're trying to test since that's relevant to the tool people are going to recommend.